# How to make intentfilter that way to open app immediately

Tags: android, react-native, deep-linking

Currently i have deep linking and everything works good, how ever when user scan the application he can choose to open with `MyApp` or any browser `Chrome` for example. How i can prevent that so it can be open only with `MyApp` if is installed. Here is how my config looks like:

```
 intentFilters: [
            {
              action: 'VIEW',
              autoVerify: true,
              data: [
                {
                  scheme: 'https',
                  host: '*1b1.art',
                  pathPrefix: '/claim',
                },
              ],
              category: ['BROWSABLE', 'DEFAULT'],
            },
          ],
```

any ideas, thanks!